# Implementing list filtering in the ViewModel of the MVVM. NET.MAUI pattern

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I want to implement filtering of the list that is obtained via an HTTP request from the server:

```
 public List<Product> Prodyct = httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Product>>("http://10.0.2.2:5192/api/Product").Result;
 public List<Product> Products
 {
     get => Prodyct;
     set
     {
         if (Products != value)
         {
             Products = value;
             OnPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
 }
```

A filtering method was found, but it was not implemented for the MVVM pattern and I tried to change it:

```
 private void OnChanged(object obj)
 {
     List<Product> TempFiltered;
     
     TempFiltered = Products.Where(contact => contact.Title.Contains(obj.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();

     foreach (var item in Prodyct)
     {
         if (!TempFiltered.Contains(item))
         {
             Products.Remove(item);
         }
         else
         {
             if (!Products.Contains(item))
             {
                 Products.Add(item);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Filtering should work, but when accessing the Product list, which contains a link to Prodyct, an attempt is made to change Prodyct and this causes an error: *System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'*

How do I implement the Product field so that I can receive it via Binding in XAML, but still interact with it?

I don't speak English well, but I hope you will understand me.

I have tried to reference the Prodyct field in XAML and work with it, but it does not receive data from the HTTP request

My XAML:

```
<StackLayout>
    <SearchBar x:Name="searchBar"
       HeightRequest="40"
       Placeholder="Search..."
       BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
       SearchCommand="{Binding TextChanged}"
       SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference searchBar}, Path=Text}"/>

    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" x:Name="cl_products">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="lcl:Product">
                <Frame Padding="2" Margin="2" HasShadow="False" BorderColor="LightGray" CornerRadius="15">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" Margin="25,0,0,0" Source="{Binding photo, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter}}"/>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                            <StackLayout Margin="4">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="10" TextColor="#006064"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Cost}" FontSize="10"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding manufacturer, StringFormat='Manufacturer: {0}'}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>                    
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

Yes, changing the parameter in the foreach loop prevented the error. But even after filtering in the display, the list remains the same as it was before filtering began

Solved the problem above by changing the type to ObservableCollection

But when changing the Product, the Prodyct also changes, which is why I can't filter more than once

Comment: you can't modify a collection while you're iterating through it.  This is a basic C# restriction.  Also, your setter for `Product` will cause an infinite recursive loop

Comment: You may try using ```foreach (var item in Prodyct.ToList())```, which copies the value of Prodyct to a new separate list. Then the error will disappear.